# Set icon size in bottomTab configuration react-native-navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, wix-react-native-navigation

I am developing an app in react native and using react-native-navigation library to create a bottom tab.

Here I am unable to provide size to bottom icons. I am using a icon of size 25*25 right now which is blurry in high resolution device. When I use larger icon (for example 30*30), icons are overlapping each other in ios only.

react-native-navigation library link - https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#

**Below is the link which I have gone through :-**

https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/3527#

https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/4420

```
Navigation.setRoot({
        root: {
            bottomTabs: {
                children: [

                    {

                        stack: {
                            id: Stackid.Stackid2,
                            children: [
                                {
                                    component: {
                                        name: ScreenId.Screen1Stack,

                                    }
                                },
                            ],

                            options: {

                                bottomTab: {
                                    text: 'Tab1',
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    icon: require('../assets/firstImage.png'), 
                                    iconColor:'red',
                                    currentTabId: Stackid.Screen1,
                                    selectedIconColor: 'green',
                                    textColor: 'white',
                                    selectedTextColor: 'green',


                                },
                                topBar: {
                                    drawBehind: true,
                                    visible: false,
                                    animate: false,
                                },
                                statusBar: {
                                    visible: true,
                                    backgroundColor: 'grey',
                                    drawBehind: false,
                                    style: "light" //Or dark
                                },
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {

                        stack: {
                            id: Stackid2,
                            children: [
                                {
                                    component: {
                                        name: ScreenId.Screen2,

                                    }
                                },
                            ],
                            options: {
                                bottomTab: {
                                    text: 'Tab2',
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    icon: require('../assets/SecondImage.png'), 
                                    iconColor:'red',
                                    currentTabId: Stackid.Screen2,
                                    selectedIconColor: 'green',
                                    textColor: 'white',
                                    selectedTextColor: 'green',

                                },
                                topBar: {
                                    drawBehind: true,
                                    visible: false,
                                    animate: false,
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        stack: {
                            id: Stackid.Stackid3,
                            children: [
                                {
                                    component: {
                                        name: ScreenId.Screen3,

                                    }
                                },
                            ],
                            options: {
                                bottomTab: {
                                    text: 'Tab3',
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    icon: require('../assets/ThirdImage.png'),

                                    iconColor:'red',            
                                    currentTabId: Stackid.Screen3,
                                    selectedIconColor: 'green',
                                    textColor: 'white',
                                    selectedTextColor: 'green',

                                },
                                topBar: {
                                    drawBehind: true,
                                    visible: false,
                                    animate: false,
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },




                ],
                tabBarOptions: {
                    style: {
                        // width: windowsWidth,
                        height: 170,
                    },
                    labelStyle: {
                        fontSize: 14,
                        color: 'black',
                    },
                }




            }
        }

    });

};

}
```

**Dependencies :-**

```
"dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "^0.57.8",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.4.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-secure-key-store": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-segmented-control-tab": "^3.3.1",

  },
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried scale?

Comment: @EdisonBiba, yes I tried scale but it is not consistent in all device and also image sharpness is very low.

Answer (score 2):

Add `images` to `assets` in Xcode and try them.

For images included via Xcode asset catalogs  use the image name without the extension:

**add Asset in Xcode**

[image: asset]

**Example**

```js
<Image source={{uri: 'AppIcon'}} style={{width: 40, height: 40}} />
```

If you want to do it differently on different platforms,
For images included in the Android drawable folder, use the image name without the extension:

```js
let appicon = Platform.OS === "ios" ? "AppIcon" : "asset:/AppIcon.png"
<Image source={{uri: appicon }} style={{width: 40, height: 40}} />
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @hong
I have implemented this but after scaling the image I am getting smaller icon in iPhone 5, 6 as compare to other device(7, X, Rr, Xs Max). Can you please suggest why it is happening?
Now a new challenge for me is to use icon for both platform natively in a single  image source.

Comment: Are the icons fixed in size? Of course, the size of the icons varies depending on the size of the screen. Because the screen is large, the icon has to be larger.

Comment: If you want to do it differently on different platforms, You can use `Platform`

Comment: I edited my answer as you wanted. If my answer was helpful, would you please check and select the 'V' and arrow?

Comment: Hi hong I am very close to resolve this issue by implementing your above solution, but there are some issue which am facing right now : 
1. I am unable to use Image because react-native-navigation library doesn't support Image.
2. When I provide height and width it is getting crash
3. I am able to use scale but it is not consistent thought all iPhone devices,
4. When I use scale the icon quality is not good, sharpness is missing here.

Comment: Here how I am using the scale factor in my code: 

 options: {
                                bottomTab: {
                                    text: 'Tab1',
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    icon: {
                                        scale:1.7,
                                        uri: Platform.OS === 'ios' ?  'tab1_ios':'tab1_androidd',

                                    },
}

react-native-navigation library link - https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/

Could you please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: icons size
1x = 24px
2x = 48px
3x = 72px